# ros2 foxy including header file from other package

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, header, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two packages, `temp_lib` and `temp_pkg`. In `temp_lib` I have a file `temp.hpp` that I would like to include in other packages, but when I attempt to do so by writing in `#include "temp_lib/temp.hpp"` in a cpp file in `temp_pkg` then it says this header cannot be found.

The problem is i'm not really sure how to set up the CMakeLists file for the library.

How can I set these packages up for this to be possible?

**LIBRARY CMAKE**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(temp_lib)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

install(TARGETS
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  )

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE)

ament_package()
```

**temp.hpp** (from `temp_lib`)

```
#ifndef TEMP_LIB__TEMP_HPP_
#define TEMP_LIB__TEMP_HPP_

#include <iostream>

#endif // TEMP_LIB__TEMP_HPP_
```

**PKG CMAKE**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(temp_pkg)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(temp_lib REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  ${temp_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(test src/temp.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(test rclcpp temp_lib)

install(TARGETS
  test
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

**temp.cpp** (from `temp_pkg`)

```
#include "temp_lib/temp.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "it works" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: for legibility I removed some repeated standard parts of the CMake files, these are

```
# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()
```

and

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389945/ros2-foxy-including-header-file-from-other-package/) by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2021-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2021-11-05**:
I think @morten's answer is a good example using ament_cmake (and I see no reason not to).

One question that's potentially just a typo. I did notice that your example temp_lib install function only installs `*.h` headers rather than `*.hpp` headers. If that's the case then temp_lib/temp.hpp won't be installed since it doesn't patch the pattern.

**Comment by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on 2021-11-23**:
that was definitely a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure is this is the "recommended" way to do it, as I am using ament commands instead of pure cmake. If someone knows how to do a pure cmake alternative I would be interested to hear.

But a possible solution I have found is with:

**lib cmake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(temp_lib)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

ament_export_include_directories(include)

ament_package()
```

**pkg cmake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(temp_pkg)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(temp_lib REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_case src/temp.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(test_case rclcpp temp_lib)

install(TARGETS
  test_case
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

**Edit**: for legibility I excluded

```
# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) with karma: 198 on 2021-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2022-08-02**:
In the pkg cmake, wouldn't you also need to include...

```
include_directories(
  ${temp_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

...before the add_executable directive?